# Error with constrained curve fitting through specific points using the cobs package: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: r, constraints, regression, curve-fitting, spline

I'm trying to find the best fitting curve through a given set of points. The fitted curve must also pass through these points. I found an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29442) on Cross Validated which suggested to use the [`cobs: Constrained B-Splines (Sparse Matrix Based)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobs/index.html) package. However, I got an error while testing it with my sample data:

```
Error in x %*% coefficients: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
```

**My question**: what caused this error and how can I fix it? I'm open to other solutions using different methods/packages too. Thanks!

```r
library(cobs)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1e-06,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y = c(1e-07,1.925,2.9625,3.469375,
        3.875,4.5315,4.89,5.09375,5.216,5.46))
dat
#>          x         y
#> 1  1.0e-06 0.0000001
#> 2  2.5e-01 1.9250000
#> 3  5.0e-01 2.9625000
#> 4  7.5e-01 3.4693750
#> 5  1.0e+00 3.8750000
#> 6  2.0e+00 4.5315000
#> 7  3.0e+00 4.8900000
#> 8  4.0e+00 5.0937500
#> 9  5.0e+00 5.2160000
#> 10 6.0e+00 5.4600000

# visual inspection
plot(dat); lines(dat)
```

[image]

```r
# define constrained points
con <- matrix(
  cbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        c(1e-06,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3, 4,5,6),
        c(1e-07,1.925,2.9625,3.469375,
          3.875,4.5315,4.89,5.09375,5.216, 5.46)), 
  ncol = 3, nrow = 10)

# curve fitting 
fit_result <- cobs(dat$x, dat$y, pointwise = con)
#> qbsks2():
#>  Performing general knot selection ...
#> Error in x %*% coefficients: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I found that the Standard Vapor Pressure equation "y = exp(a + (b/x) + c * log(x))" gave an excellent fit to the data as a simple smooth curve, but will not pass exactly through each point with the given data precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I have answered this question on [R-Help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-January/465444.html) and the OP has asked me to also answer on SO.

A solution is to explicitly set the type of `constraint` and choose a value for `lambda`. In a [final mail](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-January/465461.html), the OP gives extra information on how to fit the curve.

```
library(cobs)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1e-06,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y = c(1e-07,1.925,2.9625,3.469375,
        3.875,4.5315,4.89,5.09375,5.216,5.46))

con <- matrix(
  cbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        c(1e-06,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3, 4,5,6),
        c(1e-07,1.925,2.9625,3.469375,
          3.875,4.5315,4.89,5.09375,5.216, 5.46)),
  ncol = 3, nrow = 10)

# curve fitting
fit_result <- cobs(dat$x, dat$y,
                   constraint = "increase",
                   lambda = 0.1,
                   pointwise = con)

pred <- predict(fit_result)

plot(y~x, dat)
lines(pred[,1], pred[,2], col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Rui!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem sounds like "Spline Interpolation".

Possibly the simplest solution in R:

```
f = splinefun(dat$x, dat$y)

#simple plot
x = seq(0, 6, , 200)
plot(dat)
lines(x, f(x))
```

I note that there are different types of curve fitting. In regression modelling, for example, often the goal is to find a line or plane (which generalizes to a surface), which gives the best fit. Spline fitting and regression modelling are not always done separately, because there are cases where splines are used for regression purposes.

Note: I posted on R Help, and was asked to post here.